# Supporting an .Net Framework Lib in .Net Core 2.0 WebAPI - Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, migration, compatibility

so basicly out complete company dataaccess is based in .Net Framework 4.6.
We are only on windows, so no problems here atm.

We have a new project in which I want to use .Net Core 2.0 and WebAPI but I have to use this "old" .net Framework lib.

When I add the reference and start my project I will get an error:

Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

As far as I googled it and understand, the dataasccess lib will try to get the win auth but this isnt available in .net core (obvious) any more.

I found the nuget Microsoft.Windows.Compatilibity and after installing the error is gone.
But another one comes up:

Exactly this error:https://community.oracle.com/thread/4139377

And the only solution to this seems to be to remove the MS.Win.Comp package...

So a bit of a circle.

Any ideas?